# Can't compile driver project in Visual Studio 2019 with C++20 modules

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, wdm, wdf

**Does the MSVC support C++20 modules for Windows driver projects ?**

I enabled C++20 and compiled project, but I taked error (**C3474 could not open file DriverModule.ifc**). I tried to added path in "[Additional Module dependecies]: $(ProjectDir)DriverModule.ifc", but it wasn't fixing error.

**DriverModule.ixx**

```cpp
export module DriverModule;

export int calculate(int x);
```

**DriverModule.cpp**

```cpp
module DriverModule;

int calculate(int x)
{
    return x + 10;
}
```

**EntryPoint.cpp**

```cpp
#include <wdm.h>
import DriverModule;

extern "C" NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath);

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DriverObject);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(RegistryPath);
    int b = calculate(28);
    KdPrint(("%d", b));
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20, Modules were added in 16.8, I don't know if that extends to windows drivers or not, or if the issue is with something else entirely, as I've not used them. Have you tried similar code on a non-windows driver project? Say, just using a simple console program?

Comment: The driver stuff, quite justifiably, tends to be more conservative. I wouldn't be surprised if Microsoft holds new features back until they have good numbers proving they aren't releasing something that easily craters PCs.

Comment: @ChrisMM Yes, I used a simple console project and the modules work successfully.